# Possible impact of changing the IQ stanza timeout to 5 seconds on the XMPP server

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I've been working with mod_ping on ejabberd, and could observe this:

- `ping_interval`: Seconds
  How often to send pings to connected clients, if the previous option is enabled. If a client connection does not send or receive any stanza in this interval, a ping request is sent to the client. The default value is 60 seconds.
- `timeout_action`: `none`|`kill`
  What to do when a client does not answer to a server ping request in less than 32 seconds. The default is to do nothing.

For now, I have the ping interval as 15 seconds. A smaller value would drain the battery of mobile clients, as has been observed.

So, gauging a bit I changed the **IQ_TIMEOUT value from 32 seconds to 5 seconds** (a smaller value). This closes my connection with a relatively smaller wait now. This is a change in the wait time for receiving acknowledgement from the connected peer i.e. if the ack is not received within 5 seconds, the socket is closed by ejabberd now.

I am anxious if this impacts any other functionality of ejabberd?

What are the drawbacks of setting up a small value such as 5 seconds in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Some mobile connections have a much higher round-trip time (RTT) then 5 seconds. You are at risk in closing perfectly alive connections which such a low setting.

Comment: I didn't get the context of RTT here. 
Is it with referene to ejabberd-android client communication?

Also could you comment on the lag in ack receiving one could observe when on wifi/2G/3G data? Makes a difference?

Comment: If the RTT of the connection is greater then the IQ/ping reply timeout. Then pongs will arrive to late and the server will eventually terminate the connection because it assumes (falsely) that there was no pong.